# Copy a csv column into postgresql with autoincrement

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, npgsql

I have a csv file with 1.2 million entrys which are representing analog values e.g. current values. When I save a data record I want to insert this values in one go.

When my software has the next run, it needs to know what was the last primary key id. I thought it would be possible that the primary key stuff is handled implicite so that the next run get's it's correct primary key automatically.

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test
( id INTEGER primary key,
  value INTEGER
);
```

Additionally I have a csv coded file with only one column. The Content is as the following:

```
 value 
------
  89     
  12    
  234
```

Then I used the following command to insert my values.

```
Using writer = conn.BeginTextImport("COPY tbl_test (value) FROM
'C://temp//analog.csv'")
```

I expected, that the result would be like in the following table, but It wasn't possible to insert the datas like I exptected.

Is it possible to add the content of the csv file with help of the `COPY` command so that the id column is incremented automatically and the result would be as the following?

```
 id  | value 
-----+-------
   1 |  89
   2 |  12
   3 |  234
```

Comment: With SQLServer, you can add the ID column after with Alter Table table1 add col3 int identity(1,1)     There might be something like that in postgresql

Comment: I am not sure, because I am starting with postgres, but there is a datatype SERIAL instead of INTEGER for declaring the primary key type. I tried it already but without success.

Comment: Be friendly and uptick to acknowledge and more people will comment and post if they can :)  It's a hard question, I know....

Comment: What was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what was wrong in comments and why did not you try serial:

```
t=# CREATE TABLE tbl_test
( id serial primary key,
  value INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE

t=# copy tbl_test (value) from stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
  89
  12
  234  >> >> >>
>> \.
COPY 3
t=# select * from tbl_test;
 id | value
----+-------
  1 |    89
  2 |    12
  3 |   234
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I tested your example with success in the console. Thats exactly the behaviour that I need. I only have problems to solve this with NPGSQL. So I know now, that I really need the type SERIAL. Thanks.

Comment: Npgsql fully supports text COPY (alongside the more efficient binary copy), see http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the command line.

```
sudo -u youruser psql -d yourdatabasename -c "\COPY tablename(col1, col2, col3) FROM file.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

If you want to skip the header of the file at the end put `"CSV HEADER"`.